# Flutter Redux SnackBar

Tags: asynchronous, redux, flutter, snackbar

I am using redux in my flutter code. I have a button which on press dispatches an action to call an async API (in my middleware). What I want to do is when the api call executes and gives back response, I want to show the snackbar stating it is successfully updated data or a error message. My issue is how to show the snackbar by dispatching an action to show it. Or is there a better way to do this in redux?

Comment: You could pass callbacks (completed and error) as part of the action that the middleware can use

Comment: @aqwert Can you elaborate? I don't understand this. Plus my issue is more on how to show a snackbar after an async api response. For the values I can use the appState, right?

Comment: Added an answer

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Disclaimer:**
This is not code written in an IDE and run.. it is just a way to describe a solution to your question. There may be mistakes.

Assuming you have the Redux store and using async for the API call.

**Your page widget:**

```
... 

_onSubmit(Store<MyState> store) {
   store.dispatch(new SubmitAction(onCompleted: _onCompleted, onError: _onError))

}

_onCompleted() {
    Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(new SnackBar(
       content: new Text("Item Completed")));

}

_onError(error) {
    Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(new SnackBar(
       content: new Text("Error Occurred")));
}
```

**Your Redux middleware:**

```
apiMiddleware(Store<MyState> store, action, NextDispatcher next) {

    if(action is SubmitAction) {
        yourAPICall()
            .then((data) => action.onCompleted())
            .catchError((e) => action.onError(error));
    }

    next(action);
}
```

**MyAction class:**

```
typedef void VoidCallback();
typedef void ErrorCallback(error);
class MyAction {
   MyAction({this.onCompleted, this.onError})

   VoidCallback onCompeleted;
   ErrorCallback onError;
}
```

Some of this could be done with futures but this is simple enough.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This approached worked. The other way I found was to use a global key and in the middleware use this key to show the snackbar after getting response from the api.

Comment: Sure.. whatever works and you are happy with the level of coupling the Middleware has with the UI

Comment: What if, when submit is clicked I also send the loading action. This will trigger the current widget to be replaced with a new one, displaying a progress bar. The callbacks will be left pointing to a destroyed context. Are callbacks a safe mechanism for Stateless widgets?

Comment: Depends on the context you are passing. If you are staying on the same page you can pass the pages context, not the button's.

Comment: But is this ok with the architecture that Redux proposes?

Comment: @aqwert getting this error while showing snackbar in success call of api